# Producer Consumer message sharing not working in multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, opencv, python

i am trying to run a scenario where i have a **producer** which is capturing frames from webcam and putting it in a queue.
and then **consumer** reads image from input queue and does some processing and puts o/p image in outgoing queue.

Issue is, consumer read from queue is not blocking. Ideally it should be, also when it reads value from queue, size is always constant 128, which is wrong. I am sure size of image that I am putting in queue is far greater.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import multiprocessing
import time
import logging
import sys

import cv2


class Consumer(multiprocessing.Process):
    
    def __init__(self, incoming_q, outgoing_q):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.outgoing_q = outgoing_q
        self.incoming_q = incoming_q

    def run(self):
        proc_name = self.name
        print(f"{proc_name} - inside process_feed..starting")
        while True:
            #print(f"size of incoming_q=>{self.incoming_q.qsize()}")
            try:
                #print(f"{proc_name} - size of B incoming_q=>{self.incoming_q.qsize()}")
                image_np = self.incoming_q.get(True)
                size_of_img = sys.getsizeof(image_np)
                #print(f"{proc_name} - size of A incoming_q=>{self.incoming_q.qsize()}")
                if size_of_img > 128:
                    print(f"{proc_name} - size image=>{size_of_img}")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    self.outgoing_q.put_nowait(image_np)
            except:
                pass
        print("inside process_feed..ending")


class Producer(multiprocessing.Process):
    
    def __init__(self, incoming_q, outgoing_q):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.incoming_q = incoming_q
        self.outgoing_q = outgoing_q

    def run(self):
        proc_name = self.name
        print("inside capture_feed")
        stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        try:
            counter = 0
            while True:
                counter += 1
                if counter == 1:
                    if not self.incoming_q.full():
                        (grabbed, image_np) = stream.read()
                        size_of_img = sys.getsizeof(image_np)
                        print(f"{proc_name}........B.......=>{self.incoming_q.qsize()}")
                        print(f"{proc_name} - size image=>{size_of_img}")
                        self.incoming_q.put(image_np)
                        print(f"{proc_name}........A.......=>{self.incoming_q.qsize()}")
                    counter = 0
                
                try:
                    image_np = self.outgoing_q.get_nowait()
                    logging.info("reading value for o/p")
                    cv2.imshow('object detection', image_np)
                except:
                    pass

                if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
        finally:
            stream.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        print("inside capture_feed..ending")
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)
    stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    
    incoming_q = multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize=100)
    outgoing_q = multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize=100)

    logging.info("before start of thread")
    
    max_process = 1
    processes = []    
    processes.append(Producer(incoming_q, outgoing_q))
    for i in range(max_process):
        p = Consumer(incoming_q, outgoing_q)
        p.daemon = True
        processes.append(p)
    logging.info("inside main thread..middle")

    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    logging.info("inside main thread..ending")
    logging.info("waiting in main thread too....")
    logging.info("waiting in main thread finished....")
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    logging.info("inside main thread..ended")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out issue with my approach. I missed whole concept of pickle (serialization).

I changed my code to serialize numpy array before writing to queue and deserialize after reading it. Code started working as expected.

also printing 128 as sizeof np array is fine, i was misinterpreting that number.

```
    def serialize_ndarray(arr:np.ndarray):
        serialized = pickle.dumps(arr)
        return serialized


    def deserialize_ndarray(string):
        data  = pickle.loads(string)
        return data
```